# How to get type of a textarea

Tags: javascript

As part of a larger script I have this snippet of code:

```
if (form.elements[i].type === 'text') {
// do stuff
}
```

It works fine on input type=text but not at all on textarea. Have tried to modify the script to look like this:

```
if (form.elements[i].type === 'text' && form.elements[i].type === 'textarea') {
// do stuff
}
```

Still nothing on textarea... Any ideas please?

Comment: `<textarea>` is not a type of `<input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `<textarea>`s don't have a `type` property. You need to check the element name. `form.elements[i].tagName === 'TEXTAREA'`. (`tagName` always returns all in caps.)

EDIT: You also need to use the `||` (or) operator instead of `&&` (and). An element can't be both at the same time!

Comment: Moreover, if `type === 'text'` how can it be `=== 'textarea'` at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your checking that the type should be ***both*** `text` and `textarea`. You probably want to use the `or`-operator like this:

```
if (form.elements[i].type === 'text' || form.elements[i].type === 'textarea') {
    // do stuff
}
```